# Access Users Model foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I am writing my first Django App where I am wanting to utilise the built in user model to map to my own custom model.

My application is going to manage Users IT devices. To do this, I have a table called devices. I am wanting a foreign key per device that maps to the user model (so one user can have multiple devices).

My question is, how do I add that mapping in my model. Some thing?

```
Class Devices(model.Model):
 DeviceID = model.CharField(MaxLength=10)
 Owner = model.ForeignKey(<User??>)
```

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 2):

```
class Device(model.Model):
    deviceID = model.CharField(MaxLength=10)
    owner = model.ForeignKey(User)
```

- You should check the standarts for coding styles [Django Coding Style Standarization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

  - Use singular words for classes
  - Begin class name with capital letter
  - Begin class field with **non** capital letter
  - etc...
- You should also check oficial documentation [Django: Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

After a model is related to another via `ForeignKey` you can do following actions, If you have a Device object in a variable called `dev`:

```
dev.owner  # This return an User object, so you can access all user fields
dev.owner.username
dev.owner.email
```

Comment: Hi Liarez,Thanks for the quick response. I will have a play and get back to you.

Also, thanks for the heads up on Coding styles, I will make sure I follow them :)

Answer (score 0):

To access Django's in-built `User` model, you need to import this:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Assuming you have imported models:

```
from django.db import models
```

NOTE: it's `models` instead of `model`. This typo also exists in Liarez's answer.